# How to find nearest value and merge it with record?

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically What I want to do is to find record with closest value, pull one value from it and add create a records which consist this value. I have no idea is it even possible.

So my records looks like this

```
Wire_tag|lenght|place|
----------------------
W1      |2     |closet
W2      |2.5   |NULL
W3      |3     |NULL
W4      |4     |conveyor
W5      |5     |NULL
```

What i want to achieve to assign wire_tag where column place is not NULL with closest value of lenght to wire where column place is diffrent than null. So results i want to achieve is something like this

```
Wire_tag|lenght|place   |wire_assign
------------------------------------
W1      |2.5   |closet  |W2
W4      |3     |conveyor|W3
W4      |5     |conveyor|W5
```

Comment: I don't understand the last row of your desired result. I would expect `(W4,4,conveyor,W5)`

Comment: closest value of lenght for W1(2) is W2 (2.5). closest value of lenght for W4(4) is W3(3) and W5(5). The lenght of the original wire (W1 and W4) is lost. I edited the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's two methods, the first (nice) method relies on using common-table expressions, and I'm not sure if those will be available in the version of MySQL you are on, so the second version doesn't use any "fancy" SQL.

First I created a temporary table, you won't need this step (and it's not MySQL syntax anyway):

```
CREATE TABLE #wires (
    wire_tag VARCHAR(50),
    lenght NUMERIC(9,1),
    place VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO #wires SELECT 'W1', 2, 'closet';
INSERT INTO #wires SELECT 'W2', 2.5, NULL;
INSERT INTO #wires SELECT 'W3', 3, NULL;
INSERT INTO #wires SELECT 'W4', 4, 'conveyor';
INSERT INTO #wires SELECT 'W5', 5, NULL;
```

So replace #wires with your actual table name in the queries below:

```
--Nice way
WITH distances AS (
    SELECT
        w.wire_tag,
        w2.lenght,
        w.place,
        w2.wire_tag AS wire_assign,
        ABS(w2.lenght - w.lenght) AS distance
    FROM
        #wires w
        LEFT JOIN #wires w2 ON w2.place IS NULL
    WHERE
        w.place IS NOT NULL),
min_distances AS (
    SELECT
        wire_tag,
        MIN(distance) AS min_distance
    FROM
        distances
    GROUP BY
        wire_tag)
SELECT
    d.wire_tag,
    d.lenght,
    d.place,
    d.wire_assign
FROM
    distances d
    INNER JOIN min_distances m ON m.wire_tag = d.wire_tag AND m.min_distance = d.distance;

--Nasty way 
SELECT
    y.wire_tag,
    y.lenght,
    y.place,
    y.wire_assign
FROM
    (SELECT
        w.wire_tag,
        w2.lenght,
        w.place,
        w2.wire_tag AS wire_assign,
        ABS(w2.lenght - w.lenght) AS distance
    FROM
        #wires w
        LEFT JOIN #wires w2 ON w2.place IS NULL
    WHERE
        w.place IS NOT NULL) y
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            wire_tag,
            MIN(distance) AS min_distance
        FROM
            (SELECT
                w1.wire_tag,
                ABS(w2.lenght - w1.lenght) AS distance
            FROM
                #wires w1
                LEFT JOIN #wires w2 ON w2.place IS NULL
            WHERE
                w1.place IS NOT NULL) x
        GROUP BY
            wire_tag) m ON m.wire_tag = y.wire_tag AND m.min_distance = y.distance;
```

Gives the same results for both methods:

```
wire_tag    lenght  place   wire_assign
W1          2.5     closet      W2
W4          3.0     conveyor    W3
W4          5.0     conveyor    W5
```

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking:

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.wire_tag
        from t t2
        where t2.place is not null
        order by abs(t2.length - t.length)
        limit 1
       ) closest_wire_tag
from t
where t.place is null;
```